# Inheritance plugin for JAXB2 not working on simpleTypes

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics, xjb

I have some trouble applying xjb inheritance bindings to a simpleType. Applying it to a complexType seems to work fine.

The error I get is:

```
compiler was unable to honor this implements customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

My bindings look like this:

```
 <jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings multiple="true"
                   node="//xs:complexType[substring(@name, string-length(@name)-string-length('-e')+1)='-e']">
        <inheritance:implements>mypackage.Element</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings multiple="true"
                   node="//xs:simpleType[descendant::xs:restriction[@base='string']]">
        <inheritance:implements>mypackage.Element</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And my xsd contains the following lines:

```
   <simpleType name="checkOut">
            <restriction base="string"/>
      </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="checkIn"> 
        <restriction base="string"/>
    </simpleType>
 <complexType name="Author-e"></complexType>
```

Consequently, any attempt to apply this plugin/modification to a simpleType fails. Are simpleTypes not supported by the inheritance plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author or the [jaxb2-basics](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-basics) inheritance plugin here.

The plugin does not handle simple types.

If I am not mistaken, XJC does not (necessarily) generate classes for derived simple types. So you will probably not get `mypackage.CheckOut` or `mypackage.CheckIn` generated. So there will be no classes to add `implements mypackage.MyElement` to.